# Azure-Deployment to stage ignores service configuration

Tags: azure, deployment, visual-studio-2013, azure-cloud-services

I created a cloud service and tested it successfully locally. I added service configurations for stage and production. Here is a snippet of my staging-configuration:

[image: Service Configuration]

and here my configuration-settings:

[image: Configuration start page]

Then when I publish I set up the deployment as follows:

[image: publishing settings]

All this worked like 2 weeks ago. But now he deploys in VS and when I look into Azure Service Configure area it looks like this:

[image: Configure area in Azure after publish]

I played a little bit with the "Update development ..."-checkbox on the second screen but the result is the same.

So it ignores all the settings I made and just won't tranistion my configuration to the ine I named "CloudStage". My current Web PI tells me that I use Windows Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2013) 2.3. I don't get the point.

**Edit** 
Some more things I observed:

- No WADLogsTable and WADWindowsEventLogsTable is generated automatically in the staging storage.
- I deactivated Remote Desktop because it was one of the changes I made to monitor the event log (which wasn't useful here)
- I manually changed the connection strings in Azure Portal but it seems as if the worker is totally unaware of the storage (rebooted it with no success).

**Edit**

I recognized another thing. Here you can see a running deployment of my service:

[image: Deployment started]

See the warning-mark on the left? If I go to my Error list this is shown:

[image: Senseless warnings]

This warning is senseless since it tells me that I did everything the right way. My *.Local.csfg-files are pointing to the local storage. So?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the problem is completely on client-side. My Visual Studio (now with SDK 2.4) is doing something wrong. I set up a fresh installation with all the stuff needed :-( and there it works perfect. I'll try to determine if one of my extensions is causing the strange "Object reference not set..."-bug.

Repair-Installation of VS does not solve the problem btw.

Answer (score 3):

This seems weird.  Please check the  in your ServiceConfiguration.CloudStage.cscfg to verify the expected values. 
Have you tried updating any other property like Enabling Remote desktop? Does that get updated on your deployment? You should select the "Deployment Update" check box in the publish dialog. Now, when deploying to an existing Cloud Service, it should ask you if you want to replace it. 
If you get the Object reference error every time you right click on project, there might be some issue with the Azure SDK set up.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'll tried to switch Remote Debugging on and off and this takes place in Azure. Only the connection strings will always be set to Development.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit further now. What I did was:

1. Deleted all Services in Azure.
2. Deleted all Storage Accounts in Azure
3. Removed my Service-Project completely from solution (not the library containing the worker-logic).
4. Re-added storage-accounts in Azure.
5. Re-added services in Azure.
6. Re-added a project in the solution and added the worker-logic inside it.
7. Builded up all the publishing-stuff again.
8. Published it.

The first publish ended like the one described in my question. After I checked the "Update development..."-option in properties of my worker it finally took my transitions into the stage!

Now I recognized, that WADLogsTable was still empty. I hit the instance right in server-explorer and choosse "Update diagnostic settings...". There was an option "Transfer period" suddenly set to "None". This explained to me, why my table was empty and after I set it back to "1" my table is filling again!

Another funny thing beside: When I right-click my Cloud-project in the solution I get "Object reference not set to an instance...". When I just click it left and choose Build->Publish it works.

I just hope that I can help somebody with this. Lets see if it's stable now.

**Edit**: Yesterday it worked - today is still the same issue :-(.

Answer (score 0):

When you get "`Object reference not set to an instance..`" for a `CloudService project` you usually have some kind of mismatch. It could be that a setting in the `ServiceConfiguration` is not defined in the `ServiceDefinition`. It could also be that there is a publish profile defined in the `.ccproj` file for the `CloudService` that doesn't exist. This might also be what is causing your problems with the different configurations.

Comment: Just to clear "Object reference...". It's only displayed when I right-click the project and select "Publish". If I do the same command from the menu-bar (Build->Publish) it works. So it seems to be an issue with the VS-integration to me. But I'll check your hints and come back.